# What is the term for words pronounced like their meaning?

Tags: terminology

Example:
"A giraffe has a loooong (pronounced in an exaggerated, drawn-out manner) neck."
"I have a short (pronounced very quickly) neck."

- What is the technical term for pronouncing these adjectives in the manner described?
  I don't think 'phonaesthenes' applies, nor does onomatopoeia.

A friend's child spoke this way sometimes.  It was years ago, and at the time I'd stumbled upon the word that identified this sort of pronunciation (but have long since forgotten it...).  Sound symbolism? Ideophone?

It's not about a linguistic rule, I don't think, but a speaker's apparent elective choosing to pronounce adjectives in a way that corresponds to their meaning.

Comment: Iconicity, maybe?

Comment: I would say sound symbolism. It is a type of iconicity.

Comment: I'd call it iconic onomatopoiea. It matches time length of syllable with physical length of body features, which is already an iconic metaphor (TIME = LENGTH), and the definition of onomatopeia is 'sounding like what it means', which can only apply to aural features. Like "cock-a-doodle-do" and "looooooong".

Comment: I think it is a type of the so-called 'eye dialect'.

Comment: This is also common in music (e.g., AHA, "Hunting *high* and *low*" with *high* and *low* pitch), and I recall that it has a specific but totally different name there